# Two divs without line break

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a text on one line , with a small part of the text in different style.
Here is my code -

```
<style>

#footer {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-family:Calibri;
    display-block:inline;


}
</style>
<div id="footer">Questions? Contact us 
    <div id="email" style="color:blue; text-algin:center;display-block:inline;">abc@xyz.com</div> 
    Thank you
</div>
```

The desired output is

```
 Questions ? Contact us abc@xyz.com Thank you
```

But the output is shown below.

```html
<style>
  #footer {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    display-block: inline;
  }
</style>
<div id="footer">Questions? Contact us
  <div id="email" style="color:blue; text-algin:center;display-block:inline;">abc@xyz.com</div>
  Thank you
</div>
```

How can I get the text in one line with a part of the line being in different style

Comment: `display:inline-block;` not `display-block:inline;` also `text-align:center;` not `text-algin:center;`

Comment: Why are you using block elements?

Comment: To expand on @epascarello, you could use a SPAN here instead of a div, then you wouldn't have to modify the display property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the inner div to span

```html
<style>
  #footer {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    display-block: inline;
  }
</style>
<div id="footer">Questions? Contact us
  <span id="email" style="color:blue; text-algin:center;">abc@xyz.com</span>
  Thank you
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `display:inline-block` to `email`.

```css
#footer {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  /* display-block: inline; */
}
#email {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">Questions? Contact us
  <div id="email" style="color:blue; text-algin:center;display-block:inline;">abc@xyz.com</div>
  Thank you
</div>
```

BTW, `display-block: inline;` is not valid CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

Use "display: inline-block" instead of "display-block: inline"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use divs if you want inline elements. Also `display-block` property doesn't exist in css. Try using `<p>` elements to wrap the whole text inside your footer and `<span>` to change the color like this:

```
   <div id="footer"> 
     <p>Black Text  <span style="color: blue;"> Blue Text </span>  Black Text</p>
   </div>
```